# Is there any need to use the "+" operator to concatenate strings when printing to the screen. {Using Version 3.3.1}

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any difference between these two procedures? Or for that matter a reason to use the + operator to concatenate strings?

```
    print('Hello, World!' + \
          'Hello, World!' + \
          'Hello, World!')

   # -----------------------------

    print('Hello, World!' \
          'Hello, World!' \
          'Hello, World!')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because the automatic concatenation of strings only applies to string literals.

It won't work with variable names:

```
print(string1
      string2
      string3)
```

is a syntax error.

The automatic concatenation is a feature of the parser; if you define multiple string literals within an expression that are not separated, they get auto-joined into one when compiling, not when running the code.

See [String literal concatenation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) in the lexical analysis documentation.

Note that you don't need to use `\` continuation slashes within parethesis (such as a function call).

Comment: For this reason, as a matter of style, I use only literal concatenation, and I use string interpolation for inserting anything variable (including string variables). You can attach ``.format(...)`` to the end of the last string literal without any parentheses. To me, this is the preferred way of dealing with long strings in which I don't want to use triple quotes, while still remaining compliant with PEP 8.